# Image not fetched correctly from the specified path - Django Template

Tags: html, django, image, django-templates

I need to pass the value of a variable and add it to the image source so I can fetch my images in the template as shown.

```
<div id="Layer7">
    {% if imgs %}
        {% for i in imgs %}
        <img src="{% static "images\uploads\i"%}"">                  
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Variable `imgs` contains a list of images names so I need to attach it to the url shown in the img src in order to fetch the image. When the above code is excuted I get a broken image link with the the following url`/static/images/uploads/i` which is false.

Any help with this issue?

Comment: Use `{{STATIC_URL}}/{{i.url}}` instead - You cannot query a variable this way.

Comment: @karthikr like that <img src="{% static "images/uploads" %}/{{i.url}}"> ?!
It still didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to build manually the url for uploaded images, what you need to do is to  setuo property MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL

I assuming you have MEDIA_ROOT pointing to 'static/uploads', and STATIC_URL is '/static/', so then your MEDIA_URL must be '/static/uploads/'

After that with as simple {{ img.url }} you'll gett the full path to the file (without adding nothing before).

Comment: My MEDIA_URL is '/media/images/uploads/' and MY STATIC_URL is '/static/' so the paths are correct but whenevent I try to fetch the img by i.url I get nothing

Comment: Seeing at your question again, imgs is a list of models with an ImageField, right?... I think you are'nt doing properly in templates because .url is a property of the ImageField, so i.image.url (if image is the name of the ImageField) may works.

Comment: I have tried as follows:
<img src="{% static "images/uploads/"{{i.docfile.url}} %}"/>  but I am getting Template Syntax Error with the following:

Could not parse the remainder: '{{i.docfile.url}}' from '"images/uploads/"{{i.docfile.url}}'
Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: First of all, you cannot use a variable this way inside {% static %}, and you don't need to use {% static ..., because of the i.docfile.url will get you the full path

Comment: I have managed to get it using the following as you suggessted:
<img src="{{i.docfile.url}}"/>
The images still appear as a broken link but the path of each is correct with the image at the end of it.